# difference of random positive semidefinite matrix and positive definite matrix

Tags: positive-definite

Let $X$ be a random positive semidefinite matrix, and let $A$ be a fixed positive definite matrix.
  Then, $\forall A$,
$$
Pr[X\geq A]\leq Tr(E(X)A^{-1})
$$

Here $X\geq A$ means $A -X$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: You can use the term "Loewner order" for this order relationship.

Comment: Besides, this is the raw question. What have you attempted ? For example, is it true in dimension 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it is true for sure. I just didn't know how to prove it.

Comment: You mean that you don't know how to treat the elementary case of dimension 1 where it is no longer matrices, but **numerical** quantities ?

Comment: I know how to treat the elementary case. But, when it comes to matrix, I cannot handle.

Comment: I think that a natural extension of the dimension 1 case is by working with diagonal matrices, otherwise said, work with diagonalization relationships; I am not certain that it's the best way but this what I would attempt...

Comment: could you please give some more details or whole proof

Comment: I am sorry. What I said was just a possible direction. I don't know enough random matrices theory.

Comment: **Something puzzles me** : the $X$ on the LHS is variable, OK. But the $X$ on the RHS, because one takes a mathematical expectation, has a completely neutral role, and surely has nothing to do with the $X$ in the LHS !!! Could you check the text of your homework ?

Comment: You haven't reacted to my question: what is the fixed value of $E(X)$ ?